# How to get link part from a tag in html using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to extract display text and corresponding hyperlink from a website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import csv

source = requests.get('https://eci.gov.in/files/category/1359-general-election-2019/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
container = soup.find_all(class_="ipsType_break ipsContained")
for data in container:
    print(f'{data.a.text}\n')
```

Here `data` contains

```
<a href="https://eci.gov.in/files/file/11007-35-vellore-pc-result-election-was-held-in-august-2019/" title="View the file 35. VELLORE PC RESULT (ELECTION WAS HELD IN AUGUST 2019) ">35. VELLORE PC RESULT (ELECTION WAS HELD IN AUGUST 2019)</a>
```

`data.a.text` gives me the display text (`35. VELLORE PC RESULT (ELECTION WAS HELD IN AUGUST 2019)`) but I'm unable to extract the link part ( `https://eci.gov.in/files/file/11007-35-vellore-pc-result-election-was-held-in-august-2019/`). I want to use the above code structure only but I'm not sure how to access the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `href` attribute, simply do `data.a["href"]`. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get(
    "https://eci.gov.in/files/category/1359-general-election-2019/"
).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
container = soup.find_all(class_="ipsType_break ipsContained")
for data in container:
    print(data.a.get_text(strip=True))
    print(data.a["href"])  # <-- to access the 'href' attribute
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
35. VELLORE PC RESULT (ELECTION WAS HELD IN AUGUST 2019)
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/11007-35-vellore-pc-result-election-was-held-in-august-2019/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.The Schedule of General Election to Lok Sabha, 2019
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10993-1the-schedule-of-general-election-to-lok-sabha-2019/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. HIGHLIGHTS
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10991-2-highlights/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. List Of Political Parties Participated
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10989-3-list-of-political-parties-participated/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. List Of Successful Candidate
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10987-4-list-of-successful-candidate/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5. Number And Types Of Constituencies
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10985-5-number-and-types-of-constituencies/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6. State Wise Candidate data Summary
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10983-6-state-wise-candidate-data-summary/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7. Constituency (PC) wise summary
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10981-7-constituency-pc-wise-summary/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8. Number of Candidates Per Constituency
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10979-8-number-of-candidates-per-constituency/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9.State Wise Number Of Electors
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10977-9state-wise-number-of-electors/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10. VOTERS INFORMATION
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10975-10-voters-information/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11. State Wise Participation of Overseas Electors Voters
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10973-11-state-wise-participation-of-overseas-electors-voters/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12. State Wise Voters Turn Out
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10971-12-state-wise-voters-turn-out/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13. PC Wise Voters Turn Out
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10969-13-pc-wise-voters-turn-out/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14. PC Wise Distribution Of Votes Polled
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10967-14-pc-wise-distribution-of-votes-polled/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15. Assembly Segment Wise Information Electors
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10965-15-assembly-segment-wise-information-electors/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16. Details of Re-poll Held
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10963-16-details-of-re-poll-held/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17.State Wise Seat Won & Valid Votes Polled by Political Parties
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10961-17state-wise-seat-won-valid-votes-polled-by-political-parties/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18. Partywise Seat Won Valid Votes Polled in Each State
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10959-18-partywise-seat-won-valid-votes-polled-in-each-state/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19.Political Party Wise Deposit Forfeited
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10957-19political-party-wise-deposit-forfeited/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20. Performance of National Parties
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10955-20-performance-of-national-parties/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21.Performance of State Parties
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10953-21performance-of-state-parties/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22.PERFORMANCE OF REGISTERED (UNRECOGNISED) PARTIES
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10951-22performance-of-registered-unrecognised-parties/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23. Participation of Women Electors in Poll
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10949-23-participation-of-women-electors-in-poll/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24. Participation of Women Candidates in Poll
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/10947-24-participation-of-women-candidates-in-poll/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reiterating Guidelines for strict observance of Covid Protocols during election rallies, meetings, campaigning, etc- reg
https://eci.gov.in/files/file/13293-reiterating-guidelines-for-strict-observance-of-covid-protocols-during-election-rallies-meetings-campaigning-etc-reg/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```